# Вызвать метод из списка

Tags: c#

У меня есть список с методами

```
List<Action<object>> methods_1 = new List<Action<object>>();
methods_1.Add(delete);
methods_1.Add(upload);
methods_1.Add(open);
```

Каким образом вызвать тот или иной метод из данного списка?

Comment: По индексу `methods_1[1].Invoke()`, но паковать методы в коллекции странная практика. Есть же делегаты.

Comment: Но если честно то, что вы делаете, это, мягко говоря, так себе. Вам нужно что-то кардинально менять. Для чего вообще вам список методов?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я не должен творить чудеса, я только изучаю этот язык и пытаюсь практиковаться по-разному

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Я вас лично не критикую, я критикую ваш подход. Ответьте, пожалуйста, про цель этого списка, а я вам попытаюсь помочь. Кстати, если бы я вам не хотел помочь, я бы просто дал ответ и всё.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov суть работы программы такова: выбирается цель, в textbox вводится какая-либо команда, которая  вызывает тот или иной метод из списка методов, который у каждой цели свой. Надеюсь понятно объяснил, что-то вроде мини консоли

Comment: то есть у вас есть соответствие уникальный текст => метод, верно?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH  а что будет если юзер ошибется в написании команды?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov да, определённая команда вызывает определённый метод определённой цели

Comment: @Bulson есть список команд, вводимая строка проверяется, если такой команды нет, в textbox выводится "Неизвестная команда"

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH а чем вам в таком случае классы не угодили? У каждого класса свой тип и свои методы. Юзер выбирает цель -сиречь тип класса, а потом выбирает метод, который вызвать  на нем?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH, я бы на твоем месте не в List засовывал все, а в Dictionary. Так по крайней мере, можно по имени вызвать нужный метод. Но опять же не понимаю, в чем смысл класть методы в коллекцию?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH А можете задать новый вопрос по поводу этих методов? А этот пусть останется для истории.

Comment: @iluxa1810 возможно, пока я учусь, для меня это выглядит нормально. А в будущем возникнет идентичный вопрос, как у тебя)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov в чём суть нового вопроса должна быть?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Да пишите как есть "суть работы программы такова: выбирается цель, в textbox вводится какая-либо команда, которая вызывает тот или иной метод из списка методов, который у каждой цели свой. Надеюсь понятно объяснил, что-то вроде мини консоли". Если что подредактируем.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov попросить, чтобы альтернативный способ написали люди?

Comment: Это не альтернатива, это другой вопрос. Этот по поводу вызова метода из `List`, а тот будет про выбор структуры данных и написание алгоритма.

Comment: Сопоставление строки и метода, как это запрограммировать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610239/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если эти методы видно, то просто по имени: `delete();`, `upload();`, `open();`.

Можно просто по индексу: `var obj = /* какой-то объект */; methods_1[1](obj);`