# Сопоставление "строки" и метода

Tags: c#

Суть работы программы такова: выбирается цель, в textbox вводится какая-либо команда, которая вызывает тот или иной метод из списка методов, который у каждой цели свой. Каким образом можно реализовать сопоставление строки и метод в данном случае?
Методы имеют одинаковую сигнатуру и принимают аргумент Object. 
Например, вводимая команда "zapros" выводит на экран true или flase(зависит всё это от цели, которую выбрали)

Comment: Только лучше бы примеры добавить и подробности. То что методы имеют одинаковую сигнатуру и принимают `object` в качестве единственного параметра.

Comment: оператор `switch`?

Comment: Методы принимающие Object в качестве аргумента - очень плохие методы, я бы даже сказал негодные методы.

Comment: @Bulson дело в том, что я пытаюсь включать в свои проекты ООП. Вообще поступает объект в метод, из которого достаются список и имя: (SFile это структура)
SFile rf = (SFile)Obj;
List<File_> files_ = rf.files_;
string name_ = rf.name_;

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Вы знаете слово "цель" тут неясно что значит.

Comment: Какой-то ООП у вас неправильный. Ну, так создайте несколько типов классов, которые реализуют один и тот же интерфейс с одинаковыми методами, а в нужном месте уже вызывайте эти методы, в зависимости от типа класса будет разное выполнение метода.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov то, над чем выполняются команды

Comment: @Bulson это ООП начинающего человека, я только начинаю в нём разбираться, если бы я всё знал, мой вопрос бы здесь не появился

Comment: ОК, сейчас напишу пример.

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Вам тут предоставили несколько содержательных ответов, пожалуйста, выберите один из них как принятый или оставьте уточняющий комментарий, почему вам не подходит ни одно из решений.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример консольной программы. С помощью интерфейса организуем разное выполнение одного и того же вызова метода. Вызываем нужный метод по выбору пользователя, но выполняется он по разному в зависимости от класса.

```
//создаем интерфейс в котором описываем метод(ы)
public interface IMakeSound
{
    void Sound(int i = 1);
    void Noise();
}

//cоздаем два класса реализующие этот интерфейс
public class Car : IMakeSound
{
    public void Noise()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ИИИИИИИ!");
    }

    public void Sound(int count  = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Би-би!");
        }
    }
}

public class Cow : IMakeSound
{
    public void Noise()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("УУУУУУ!");
    }

    public void Sound(int count = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Му-му!");
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 0;
        IMakeSound target = null;

        while (i == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите цель (Корова, Машина, Выход):");
            string targetString = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (targetString)
            {
                case "Корова":
                    target = new Cow();
                    i = 1;
                    break;
                case "Машина":
                    target = new Car();
                    i = 1;
                    break;
                case "Выход":
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Цель указана неверно, для выхода наберите Выход");
                    break;
            }  

        }

        while (i == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите задачу (Шум, Звук, Выход):");
            string targetDoing = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (targetDoing)
            {
                case "Шум":
                    WantNoise(target);
                    i = 2;
                    break;
                case "Звук":
                    WantSound(target);
                    i = 2;
                    break;
                case "Выход":
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Задача указана неверно, для выхода наберите Выход");
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void WantNoise(IMakeSound obj)
    {
        obj.Noise();   
    }

    private static void WantSound(IMakeSound obj)
    {
        obj.Sound(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я изменил пример с учетом ЦЕЛЬ->Действие

Answer (score 5):

Для данной программы можно реализовать сопоставление с помощью словаря:

```
var methodTable = new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>
{
    ["delete"] = delete,
    ["upload"] = upload,
    ["add"] = add
};
```

где `delete`, `upload`, `add` методы программы.

Затем проверять наличие данного метода с помощью метода `ContainsKey` и в случае наличия вызывать по ключу.

---

Если имена методы совпадают с ключами то можно также использовать оператор `nameof`:

```
var methodTable = new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>
{
    [nameof(delete)] = delete,
    [nameof(upload)] = upload,
    [nameof(add)] = add
};
```

---

Также можно просто применять `if` и `switch` для проверки ключа.

Если нужна нечувствительная к регистру проверка, то используйте к примеру
`if ("delete".Equals(textbox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`
или для `switch` приведите текст в нижний или верхний регистр с помощью `ToLowerInvariant` или `ToUpperInvariant` соответственно.

---

Ещё можно использовать рефлексию, итерируюсь по нужным классам, находить нужный метод. Но этот приём следует использовать с большой осторожностью.

Comment: Если у каждой цели свой набор методов?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH То есть группа, которая выполняется по очереди?

Comment: команда выполняет метод , в зависимости от цели, которая была выбрана вначале, то есть вызывается метод конкретной цели, у каждой цели свой набор методов

Comment: "команда выполняет метод" понял, а дальше ничего не понял. Что значит то, что было раньше?

Comment: Представьте, вы пишите "привет" другу, он отвечает " привет". Пишите врагу, он пишет "оскорбление". Так же и здесь. Команда выполняет метод, в зависимости от того, с чем мы работаем или кому эту команду пишем, так понятнее?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Нет, потому что я не понимаю, что такое цель более конкретно. Чтобы вам помочь вы должны описывать чтобы это было наглядно. Что такое цель чисто физически? Текстовое поле? имя пользователя ПК?

Comment: Цель - это ПК (ненастоящий, проект в виде игры)

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Я не очень вас понимаю. И я просто устал уже и пойду спать, но дам вам совет: пострайтесь переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы вас поняли. Объясняйте простыми словами, чтобы можно было бы понять вас со стороны. Представьте, что вы первый раз читаете этот вопрос и попробуйте его понять. Ставить задачу и выделять из неё фрагменты — важный навык программиста.

Comment: Благодарю за старания, я прочту пару документаций на неизвестные мне темы, ещё раз переосмыслю работу программы и постараюсь придти к решению.Доброй ночи.

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Обновил ответ, добавил также пункты про `if`/`switch` и про рефлексию.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `switch` или `if`.

Анализируешь текст юзера и условными операторами вызываешь нужный метод.

Если методы имеют одинаковую сигнатуру, то можешь поместить эти методы в `Dictionary<string,delegate>` и по ключу дергать нужный метод.

А еще есть паттерн "[команда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))"

Comment: Если у каждой цели те же методы выполняются по разному?